# SQL Server CPU getting pegged after day or two of uptime

Tags: sql-server

I have a few SQL Server 2016 servers on Windows Server 2016.  Lately they've begun having major slowdown issues with the CPU being pegged.  If I reboot it resolves the problem but over the next 24-48 hours will get slower and back to that state.  It is almost like something is building up as it runs and a reboot clears that out but obviously a reboot every other day isn't a viable solution for us.

Any idea what could be causing this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Many things can conducts to this situation...

1. MAX SERVER MEMORY without any limitation
2. heavy functional workload without CPU adequation (cursors, UDF...)
3. applications and services that's running on the same machine as your SQL instance (antivirus as an example)
   ...